# Create a baseline to line up plots and then fit a Gaussian to each

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, gaussian, baseline

I am trying to line up the attached plots so I can properly fit Gaussians to them but am not sure how to do so. I want them to have the same baseline. This is how I read in the data:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8), dpi=360)
plt.xlabel('wavenumbers (cm^-1)', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('absorbance', fontsize=16)
plt.xlim(4000,650)
for i in range((len(data.columns))):
    if i%2 == 0:
        xdata = data.iloc[100:,i]
        ydata = data.iloc[100:,i+1]
        plt.plot(xdata,ydata, label = str(data.columns[i+1]))
```

Then I use a Gaussian function to fit to my data but it doesn't work.

```
#locations of peaks to bias model
peak_locations = [985] #enter values here for peak locations
numb_of_peaks = len(peak_locations)
def gaussian_basis(x, xk , sigma = 1):
    # x is a vector
    # k is the "index" of the basis
    # sigma is the standard deviation
    return np.exp(-((x - xk)**2/(2*sigma**2)))
```

The image of my data is attached. How can I have the plots have the same baseline to show the peaks increasing?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcsZW.jpg

Comment: A start, you might try subtracting each individual curve's absorbance value at wavenumber = 2750.